# How to calculate retention from New and Active User numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

I work at a mobile gaming company and retention is one of the most important metrics there is for an app. Recently there have been some questions regarding the accuracy of this metric as shown by our 3rd party analytics provider.

Presumably since I have both the number of New Users, and Active Users by day, I should be able to calculate out some overall retention rate (within some amount of noise).

I was going down a Linear Algebra route, but I'm unsure how to solve something with noise (my LA is mighty rusty). 
For example, I have New Users by day:
$$
\mathbf{N} =  \begin{vmatrix} N_0 \\ N_1 \\ \vdots \\ N_m \end{vmatrix}
$$

And Active Users by day:
$$
\mathbf{A} =  \begin{vmatrix} A_0 \\ A_1 \\ \vdots \\ A_m \end{vmatrix}
$$

Assuming a Retention Matrix with some noise, I would get $\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{N} = \mathbf{A}$ 
where R is something like:
$$
\mathbf{R} =  \begin{vmatrix} R_0+\epsilon_{00}& 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ R_1+\epsilon_{01} & R_0+\epsilon_{10} & 0 & ... & 0 \\ R_2+\epsilon_{20} & R_1+\epsilon_{21} & R_0+\epsilon_{22} & ... & 0 \\ \vdots \\ R_m+\epsilon_{m0} & R_{m-1}+\epsilon_{m1} & R_{m-2}+\epsilon_{m2} & ... & R_0+\epsilon_{mm} \end{vmatrix}
$$

Generally, the first day $A_0 = N_0$ because there are no previous users, therefore $ R_0 = 1$.
Day 2 would be comprised of all of $N_1$ along with the retained portion of $N_0$ so $A_1 = N_1 + (R_1+\epsilon_{10})\times N_0$, and so on.

How would I get my array of retention numbers $ [R_1, R_2, R_3, .., R_m] $ with the smallest error ($\sum \epsilon^2$?) ?

I'm also completely open to other ways of solving this.
Thanks!

Comment: As described, it is a convex minimization problem: let $\mathbf{E}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{R}}$ be your variables. Then,
$\min_{\mathbf{E}, \hat{\mathbf{R}}} \|\mathbf{E}\|^{2}_{F}$, subject to $(\mathbf{E}+ \hat{\mathbf{R}}) \mathbf{N} = \mathbf{A}$, and some additional linear constraints, namely upper triangular part of both $\mathbf{E}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{R}}$ equal to zero, as well as equality constraints among the entries of $\hat{\mathbf{R}}$. Of course the variables are fewer and it can be written more efficiently. Does this help?

Comment: Definitely helpful! But I'm not familiar enough with type of problem to know how to proceed. Any more specific steps you could walk me through, or point me at a link would be greatly appreciated! I'll do some reading tonight and see what I can figure out based on what you said.

Comment: Hopefully, you won't need to read a lot!
For convex optimization, I typically use CVX (http://cvxr.com/cvx/) in Matlab. For more general problems, CVX handles only problems of moderate size, so it depends how large your $\mathbf{N}$ is. But the above problem is quite simple, I think. Michael Grant, the creator of CVX is on this site as well so maybe you can ask him!
There might be other tools as well, but I have personally not used any. A custom solver for this problem might not be too hard to make, but will require way more studying (or help)!

Comment: @m.a. I've been reading into the cvxopt library for Python to solve the problem. I think I'm getting there, but haven't quite fully solved it yet. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Based on your info, I've restructured the calculation such that I turn it into a more familar convex problem: $\min\|\mathbf{A}*\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^{2}$ where x is my Retention array. Using a python library named CVXPY, I can set constraints (0<=x<=1) and have it solve the problem. It seems to be working with real data up to n ~5, but after that, the solvers can't seem to find a solution. It's useful, but I was hoping to get solutions for n > 30. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: I am not sure what your formulation is. I think that in CVX you should be able to pretty much express your problem as you have described it in words. According you what you described there should be approximately $n^{2}/2$ variables $\epsilon_{ij}$ and $n$ variables $R_{i}$. I would expect that especially for this problem, the solver can handle $n$ much larger than $5$. If I find the time, I will try and let you know!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19342/discussion-between-zaphod-and-m-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a candidate solution using CVX in Matlab.
I have assumed that the retention values you are looking for should be positive. If not, remove the constraint R >= 0. Similarly, you may want to add other constraints.

```
% I assume you have initialized two vectors A and N of length m each.

cvx_begin

    variable E(m,m) lower_triangular;
    variable R(m,m) lower_triangular;

    minimize norm(E,'fro');
    subject to
        for k=0:m-1
            for i = k+1:m,
               R(i,i-k) ==  R(k+1,1);
            end
        end
        (E+R)*N == A;
        R >= 0;
cvx_end
```

After the code runs, you can access the variable values E and R. I tried on some arbitrary $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{N}$.
The code runs for $m>30$.